# Компиляция игры на Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x

Здравствуйте. Допустим, есть игра, написанная на Python 3. Она использует `pygame` и импортируемые модули из подкаталогов.

Что нужно сделать с этой игрой, чтобы в результате вместо файлов `.py` получить бинарники для разных операционных систем (`.exe` с иконкой под Windows, исполняемый файл Linux и т.п.) и установочный файл, который бы устанавливал зависимости в виде Python 3 и pygame, создавал ярлыки?

Модули из подкаталогов должны быть `.pyc`.

В общем, надо чтобы исходный код был недоступен для изменения и обычный пользователь мог парой кликов без проблем установить игру и начать играть.

Как это можно сделать?

В данный момент игра запускается только через терминал, что не есть хорошо для такого проекта.

Comment: Исходный код в любом случае останется доступен для изменения

Comment: Посмотрите на py2exe, cx_Freeze и другие подобные проекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, самый лучший вариант, распространять пакет игры вместе с virtualenv. В каталоге проекта сделайте файл main.py, из которого соберете exe файл для пользователя, который в свою очередь скачает и становит необходимые зависимости.